# URL Type Hierarchy in Adobe DTM

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to create a page type hierarchy where I can use it both a page hierarchy as well as props and evars, using the page URL. In a nutshell my URL would look something like this:

http://www.domain.com/BrandHomePage/SuperCategory/ProductCategory/Product

The mindset is to take the URL and use a data element to split the URL, and then capture the values into separate data elements that could also be used in a page hierarchy.

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4"
var parts = url.split('/').splice(2);
console.log(parts);

var baseUrl = parts[0];
var part1 = parts[1];
var part2 = parts[2];
var part3 = parts[3];
var part4 = parts[4]
```

My question is, would it even be possible to capture each individual portion of the URL into separate data elements? Or is my approach overkill.

Comment: of course it's possible.. you just wrote the code for it, didn't you? ;)  there is of course a more elegant way to do it, though. For starters, use `location.pathname` instead.

Comment: @CrayonViolent - you're the type of person I'd love to go to lunch with, and just absorb your knowledge. :) I somewhat wrote the code with a little help. What I'm trying to wrap my mind around is how the data element will parse it in a dynamic manner, but also parse it if not all values are there. Meaning: not all four values will exist and would be dynamic depending on the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Create a Data Element

The following will create a **Data Element** that returns an array containing up to 4 elements, depending on how many dir levels there are in the URL.

Go to **Rules** `>` **Data Elements** `>` **Create New Data Element**

**Name** it "hier1" (no quotes).

Choose **Type** `Custom Script` and click **Open Editor**.

Add the following code to the code box:

`return location.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean).slice(0,4);`

When you are done, **Save Changes**.

> ### Populate the Hierarchy Variable

Here is an example of populating `hier1` on page view.

Go to **Overview** `>` **Adobe Analytics Tool Config** `>` **Pageviews & Content**

Under **Hierarchy**, select `Hierarchy1` from the dropdown (this is shown by default).

To the right of the dropdown, in the first field, add `%hier1%`

Leave the other 3 fields blank.

Leave **Delimiter** as default comma `,` (it doesn't matter what you put here).

**Note:** DTM stringifies the returned array (`String(Array)` or `Array.toString()`) from the **Data Element**, which is effectively the same as doing `Array.join(',')`. This is why the above shows to only put the **Data Element** reference in the first field, and the **Delimiter** is ignored.

If your implementation uses a delimiter other than a comma, see additional notes below.

> ### Additional Notes

### Populating other Variables

You can also reference `%hier1%` to populate other variable fields in the **Global Variables** section. Note that the data element will be stringified with default comma delimiter.

Alternatively, you may consider using [Dynamic Variable](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/dynvars_overview.html) syntax (e.g. `D=h1`) as the value, to shorten the request URL. If you are using the latest AppMeasurement and Marketing Cloud Service libraries, this isn't a big deal (the libs will automatically use a POST request instead of GET request if the request URL is too long).

### Using the Data Element in Custom Code Boxes

You can use `_satellite.getVar('hier1')` to return the data element. Note that this returns an *array*, e.g. `['foo','bar']`, so you need to use `.join()` to concatenate to a single delimited string value.

### Using a different Delimiter

**If your implementation uses a delimiter other than a comma** (`,`) and you use the same alternate delimiter for all your variables, you can update the **Data Element** as such:

`return location.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean).slice(0,4).join('[d]');`

Where `[d]` is replaced by your delimiter. Note that this will now cause the **Data Element** to return a single concatenated `String` value instead of an `Array`. Using `%hier1%` syntax in DTM fields remains the same, but you will no longer need to use `.join()` in **Custom Code** boxes.

**If your implementation uses different delimiters for different variables**, implement the **Data Element** per the original instructions in the first section. You may use %hier1% syntax in DTM fields only if the delimiter is a comma. For all other delimiters, you will need to populate the variable in a custom code box and use a `.join('[d]')`.

### Capturing more than Four Directory Levels

Since you are no longer trying to put a value in four `hierarchy` fields, you may consider pushing more levels to `hier1` or other variables.

In the **Data Element**, change the `4` in `.slice(0,4);` to whatever max level of dirs you want to capture. Or, if you want to capture all dir levels, remove `.slice(0,4)` completely.